# Classifying topological spaces by measures

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, category-theory

While looking at some spaces, I happend to know, that in some spaces (like $\mathbb R^n$) Null sets have topological properties(defining the Algebra by the open sets)!

some examples: in $\mathbb R^n$ a Null set is totally-non-connected, nowhere-dense seems to emply Nullnes, in some spaces every null has a empty interior,but in others not;and more...

so my question is:

1. Are there any usefull functors from *TOP* to the "category of measures"(or whatever its called), like the simple  ones to *GROUP*?
2. Where can i find some book on this topic?

Comment: Not all measures are defined on Borel $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: even in the reals there are totally-disconnected nowhere dense sets of positive measure!

Comment: and a line is a connected null set in the plane...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma so it is something that can show the difference between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$!

Comment: @user160823 the connectedness argument already does; no need to consider measures